# Use Another Modules Method in Module in Nest.JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to create system where i can create different axios instances for different modules.

the problem I'm facing is that i am not able to provide custom baseURL to the service.

Tried to do it using "useFactory", but "axiosService" is resolved as undefined.

*webhook.module.ts*

```
@Module({
  imports: [AxiosModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'WebhookClient',
      useFactory: (axiosService: AxiosService) => {
        console.log(axiosService); // undefined
        return axiosService.create('http://apiurl.com/api');
      },
    },
  ],
})
export class WebhookModule {}
```

*axios.module.ts*

```
export const AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN = 'AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN';

@Module({
  providers: [AxiosService, { provide: AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN, useValue: axios }],
  exports: [AxiosService],
})
export class AxiosModule {}
```

*axios.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class AxiosService extends HttpService {
  async create(url: string) {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you've missed the `inject` propert in factory provider. There's no way to tell to NestJS that you want to inject `AxiosService` without such property due TS reflection limitations. Read the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory